K-theory of inverse limit
Is there any textbook reference for the topological K-theory to be a continuous functor? It is well known for C*-algebras, but I don't see a direct proof for (compact Hausdorff) spaces.
More precisely, I want an isomorphism $K^0(\operatorname{lim}_{i \in I} X_i) \cong \operatorname{colim}_{i \in I} K^0(X_i)$, where $X_i$ are (non-empty) compact Hausdorff spaces, and I is a directed set (more generally, filtered category). One idea would be to use Gelfand duality and invoke the result for C*-algebras, but I was looking for some idea pertaining to vector bundles. Perhaps the natural map $\operatorname{colim}_{i \in i} \operatorname{Vect}(X_i) \rightarrow \operatorname{Vect}(\operatorname{lim}_{i \in I} X_i)$ is an isomorphism, and then we are done since Grothendieck group functor is a left adjoint and so preserves colimits?
Any help will be appreciated.

Are you sure you've dualized correctly? Shouldn't the topological version send a colimit to a limit?

Since for C^*-algebras colimits are sent to colimits, I was wondering whether limits in spaces go to colimits...

This doesn't look right to me, $K^0$ is close to being representable (it is representable in the homotopy category) so naively one expects it might send colimits to limits, not the other way around. Can you state the precise form of the result for $C^{\ast}$-algebras? I wasn't able to find it by googling.

See Theorem 4.3.1 here : https://www.impan.pl/swiat-matematyki/notatki-z-wyklado~/k_theory.pdf

Interesting, thank you. This isomorphism is not obvious to me topologically even in the case that the $X_i$ are all finite and discrete. You can write down a diagram of finite discrete spaces whose cofiltered limit (inverse limit) is the Cantor set ${ 0, 1 }^{\mathbb{N}}$, and I don't have any clear direct sense of what $K^0$ of this thing ought to be but apparently it's the colimit on the RHS. Hmm.
